# Flex Mobile feedback while loading images

Tags: image, apache-flex, mobile, loading, busyindicator

i got some spark image components in my app with embedded src. if the view will pushed to the stage, the images begins to load ... and while the loading progress... i cant show an busyindicator because the thread is loading... flash couldn't animate the busyindicator and load images at the same time :-(

how can i resolve that problem? I know air/flash is single treaded :-/ i don't understand the sense of a busyindicator.. because it won't work while loading :-(

A BusyIndicator is a component to show activity...

Comment: Looks like your Embeded image is really big in size. 1. Is there a reasons to embed a big image on a mobile device? 2. Can you skip embedding and dynamically load the image when needed? this way the busy indicator should not freeze.

Comment: embedded or not embedded ... the indicator don't animate while loading :-(

Comment: hmmm... This is really strange! can you post some sample code. Also on what device are you trying to do this ?